# React native error "developement server" returned error code 500

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I have just started fresh project on react native. When I run react-native run-android I get the following error
[image]

I have no idea where it is coming from or why they appear.

```
Node js is showing the following 
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2018:08:45:01 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.10.0"
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./../../../../../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` from `C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ART\ReactNativeART.js`: The module `./../../../../../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` could not be found from `C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ART\ReactNativeART.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:209:697)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:222:485)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:149:25)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:316:29)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:312:16)
    at C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:169:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\my dell\Desktop\VKA2018\AarogyaS\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:271:307)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

Comment: Are you running `react-native run-android` command inside the project folder? Is there an index.js file there?

Comment: Is the development server running correctly?

Comment: there is.. and development server is running correctly..

Comment: what version of RN are you running?

Comment: my current react version is 0.55.4

Answer (score 0):

1- update your package.json, change react-native version from 57.2 to 57.1 as follows :

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1"
  },
```

2- run: npm install and try again